# Could someone explain this(integral definition from Spivak's Calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

He gives a function $f(x) = 0, x \neq 1$ and $f(x) =1, x =1$ .Basically the function gives 1 of it's 1 and 0 if it's anything else.This is the function graph:

[image]

Then we suppose $P = {t_0,.......,t_n}$ is a partition of $[0, 2]$ with $t_{j - 1} < 1 < t_j$

And then he says that from that we get:
$m_i = M_i = 0$ if $i \neq j$
So this is the first thing I don't understand - he says if $i$ is not equal to $j$, then $m_1$ (the rectangle that is covered by the graph) and $M_1$ (the rectangle that covers the graph) are both zero area?

How did he figure that?$t_{j - 1}$ has an index not equal to $j$ and at its position the rectangle is 1 unit high, it's not zero. And since the graph is rectangular, both $m_i$ $M_1$ are 1 unit high for $i = j-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The interval with subindex equal to $j$, i.e., $[t_{j-1},t_j]$ is the interval that contains $t=1$ in its interior: $t_{j-1}<1<t_j$.  Note Spivak specifies this!

Now $M_i=\sup\{f(t):t\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}$ and $m_i=\inf\{f(t):t\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}$. If $i\neq j$, $1\notin [t_{i-1},t_i]$, so $f=0$ in said intervals. Thus it's infimum and supremum there is $=0$.